# How Azure Synapse stores data

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How Azure Synapse stores data when it stores data in data warehouse table ?

is it on Azure storage blobs or on in blocks on  SSD disk
Any example  using table will be of good help

Comment: Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the data in your workspace default ADLS Gen2 account or you can link an ADLS Gen2 or Blob storage account to your workspace through "**Manage**" > "**Linked Services**" > "**New**" (The steps below will refer to the primary ADLS Gen2 account).

You can find more information on [data in a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-storage) here

For further more details I would recommend this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is).
This [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started) gives a step by step process on how to get started with azure synapse analytics and there few samples available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about SQL Pools, it likely stores data similar to other data warehouse platforms like Snowflake, Redshift etc with decoupled storage in blob storage. From my understanding, the SQL Pool under the bonnet is really an abstraction of a spark engine.

With Synapse Workspaces, on-demand spark clusters, sql serverless run off data stored in the Data Lake storage accounts which you're able to set up as provided by @SwethaKandikonda-MT.